# PHP / MySQL - Return values in one column

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need to select same values in 1 column, for example:
`Select * from Table,` this needs to return like this:

```
ColumnName | ColumnValue
google         1,2,3,4
facebook       1,2,3,5
```

The actual query, returns this.

```
ColumnName | ColumnValue
google           1
google           2
google           3
google           4
facebook         1
facebook         2
facebook         3
facebook         4
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Google for group_concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ColumnValue SEPARATOR ', ') FROM table GROUP BY ColumnName;
```

Considering the reasoning behind relational databases though, you should be cautious about purposely denormalizing your results.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT ColumnName, GROUP_CONCAT(ColumnValue) AS `ColumnValues`)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ColumnName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY` function:

```
SELECT ColumnName, GROUP_CONCAT(ColumnValue) AS ColumnValues FROM Table GROUP BY ColumnName
```

If you don't want allow duplicate values in the list such as `1,2,2,2,3,4` then add `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT ColumnName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColumnValue) AS ColumnValues FROM Table GROUP BY ColumnName
```